# Answering a bijective counting question

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question which I am not sure how to write out. This is my following approach and if it is not right could you tell me a better way to answer this question?

Question:
In how many ways can $k$ elements be chosen from an $n$-element set $\{x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}...x_{n}\}$

My answering attempt:
There is a bijective mapping between the permutation of $\{x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}...x_{n}\}$ and an $n$ size bit sequence of $k$ 1s and $n-k$ 0s
$$Therefore =>\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

So again, does this answer seem satisfactory or would you write it out in a better way?

EDIT: The answer needs to be a combinatorial argument

Comment: What you wrote seems good

Comment: It need not to use bijective mapping. It is equal to $C_n^k$ immediately.

Comment: Hi paul. I should have added that i needed a combinatorial argument so i do need to talk about bijective mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it official, I'll post an answer :)

As I said above, your answer is correct, and to strengthen things up:

We can map the set in the question to the set of all n-bit sequences with exactly k 1's.
if position i in the bit sequence is a 1 then it means that xi is selected.